# How to run a Xcode Cloud workflow when a specific PR is merged?

Tags: xcode, workflow, cicd, xcode-cloud

I have managed to run some Xcode Cloud workflows when launching a new PR, BUT, is there any way to run a specific workflow when this PR is finally merged?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could have a workflow that triggers when the target branch changes. ie, if your PR is from a branch off `develop`, create a workflow that runs whenever there is a push to `develop`.